# Table data insert from another table with an order sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

In my project I need to insert a table data from another table. I trying to write this sql code. But this order by option is not working while inserting the data. Here is my code:

```
INSERT INTO StudentInfo_MeritPosition
       ( ID,
         Name,
         MeritPosition,
         SSC,
         HSC,
         First,
         Second,
         Third,
         Fourth,
         Fifth
       )
       SELECT ID,
              Name,
              MeritPosition,
              SSC,
              HSC,
              First,
              Second,
              Third,
              Fourth,
              Fifth
       FROM StudentInfo
       ORDER BY MeritPosition
```

The above code inserting data into database. But not in the order format.
I need to know if there any way our for this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Your code is perfectly fine. Please clarify what is your problem. Your phrase "But not in the order format" is not clear at all.

Comment: actually my data is inserted into StudentInfo_MeritPosition table. but I need the data in merit position order. But it is inserted what the StudentInfo table has.

Comment: "Order format " means like some student position 3,2,5,9,6 in this format. But when new data will save in database it will save in the merit position column like 2,3,5,6,9.

Answer (score 3):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  When you retrieve data from the table, the data has no particular order, unless you specify `order by`.  So, you can just retrieve the data as:

```
select mp.*
from StudentInfo_MeritPosition mp
order by mp.MeritPosition;
```

You can make this query more efficient by adding an index on `StudentInfo_MeritPosition(MeritPosition)`.

Comment: I actually can't get the correct output. If you please write the full command for me.

Comment: @asmmorshed . . . This is the entire SQL query for retrieving the results in order.  It has nothing to do with the `insert`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a temp table to order in any way you want.  In my opinion it's easier to assemble a temp table first, then order those results and select them into the table you're trying to populate in a given order.  This way you can translate it to a stored procedure and feed it the parameter of "column name" and "ASC or DESC."  The temp table will take a bit longer to work with since you're selecting, ordering, reselecting, and inserting. However, the end result is much more robust than a 1 time query allowing you to use any column name, and ASC or DESC.  Just remember that when you do select the results into your permanent table, you leave out the primary key (typically [P_ID]) column form your select into statement.

Answer (score 0):

So, to improve on Gordon's answer, you could write something like what follows:

```
 DECLARE @fromTbl, @sortCol, @orderByCol VARCHAR(50)
 EXEC('
 select mp.*
 from /* StudentInfo_MeritPosition* / ' + @fromTbl + 'mp
 order by /* mp.MeritPosition */ mp.' + @orderByCol + ' ' + @sortOrder;'

   /* If you wanted to debug it and make sure your parameters are being
   generated correctly, you can use the PRINT function instead of 
   Exec('Your statement above') */
```

Then, if you turn it into a SP you can pass in the three parameters table, order by column, and sort order (ASC|DESC) and bypass the temp table creation process I mentioned previously.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
INSERT 

/*+append*/

INTO StudentInfo_MeritPosition
       ( ID,
         Name,
         MeritPosition,
         SSC,
         HSC,
         First,
         Second,
         Third,
         Fourth,
         Fifth
       )
SELECT *
FROM ( 
      SELECT ID,
             Name,
             MeritPosition,
             SSC,
             HSC,
             First,
             Second,
             Third,
             Fourth,
             Fifth
      FROM StudentInfo
      ORDER BY MeritPosition );
```

Comment: it is not working. it shows The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views this error